# How to solve the distribution

Tags: probability

How about when the normal distribution question ask probability with the modulus in the $Z$ score...example:                    $P(|Z|>k)=0.4749$, find the absolute value (modulus) of $k$...it's very confusing...

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

$P(|Z|> k) = P(\{Z> k\} \cup \{Z < -k\}) = P(Z> k) + P(Z<-k)$,
since $\{Z> k\}$ and  $\{Z < -k\}$ are disjoint. $Z$ is likely centered, so $P(Z> k) = P(Z<-k)$ and $P(|Z|> k) = 2P(Z<-k)$. Moreover, $P(Z<-k) = F(-k)$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $Z$. Using for instance Matlab or R you can compute $F^{-1}$ (the quantile function, or inverse cdf) of $Z$.

Therefore, you have $$0.4749 = 2P(Z<-k) \Leftrightarrow 0.23745 = F(-k) \Leftrightarrow -F^{-1}(0.23745) = k.$$